# curl command not working to upload file , if file is already present on jfrog artifactory

Tags: curl, artifactory

The following `curl` command:

```
curl -v -H X-JFrog-Art-Api:<API-Key> -X PUT "http:<artifactory-url>:<port>/<path>/test.exe" -T test.exe
```

Returns bad gateway error 502, if test.exe is already present on the artifactory url. How do I overwrite this file ?

Answer (score 1):

You can overwrite a fill only if the user is having the overwrite permissions on the repository. Please make sure the user has permissions.

on the other hand 502 indicates that there is an issue with proxy configuration. My request is to share more information if the user above user permission didn't fix the issue. error log messages from Artifactory + reverse proxy will be helpful

Answer (score 0):

The issue may not be necessarily a 502 from the Artifactory side.
Apache is known to send 502s instead of 403/401 when there is a redirect involved.
I'd suggest the same call with an admin user or a user with the correct permissions; it's possible the API key is not correct or the user just hasn't been given the right permissions.

It's also possible the path is wrong; depending on your configuration and version the path may need to have "/artifactory/" after the port, and if not given it may fail the request.

Also could be that the repository is not local, and you are pushing to a repo that does not accept uploads.